# Using gpg through proxy with non-root user not working

Tags: arch-linux, proxy, gpg

For a bit of context: I'm trying to install Spotify with `yay`, and it says some PGP keys need to be imported, but it's failing saying "no keyserver available". Sure enough, if I manually call `gpg --rcv-keys ...`, it throws the same error. What puzzles me is that running the `gpg` command with `sudo` works fine.

I consulted the [GnuPG Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG), as well as the [Pacman troubleshooting section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Package_signing#Cannot_import_keys):

- I tried all the servers from the latter in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, although the default one (`hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net`) seems to work fine for root, since `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf` doesn't exist. It didn't work with any.
- I have `honor-http-proxy` in both `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf` and `/root/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf`, and the env var `http_proxy` is set.
- The files under `~/.gnupg/` are definitely read correctly, if I set `debug-level guru` I do get more output, and I can see the different servers being tried.

I found [this message](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2016-October/056867.html) that suggested running `dig +trace hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net`, and I get a timeout with or without `sudo` so I'm not sure if that's really indicative of anything. Somewhere else I read it could be a problem with DNS, but then why can I receive keys with `sudo gpg ...`?

Any other ideas?